# Jekyll: Generator to link to all subpages in a static hierarchy

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to write a static site with Jekyll that has a few layers to it. What's the best way to generate links to all subpages within a section?

For example, if I have a site structure like this:

```
landing
- Topic A
  - Content 1
  - Content 2
  - Content 3
- Topic B
  - Content 1
  - Content 2
  - Content 3
```

What would be the best way to create links to each of the Content pages from its Topic page? And, is there a simple way to link to all the Topic pages from the landing?

These are not posts, just static pages. It would be really great if I could just do `{% for topic.each %}` ...etc. and print the links out.

Comment: if I understand well, you don't want to put this page into topic, and use "categories' to sort and create the generated premalink ?

Comment: ...I'm not quite sure what you mean? Each of the levels is a folder, and each contains an index.md file as well as the md files for the sub-pages.

Comment: there is more than one approach to generate this structure, you can either put the md files in post, or create specific collections, I'll explain each method in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use posts for this purpose (as yaitloutou suggests). I would read the hierarchy from the directory structure (solution 1) or create two seperate collections (solution 2). You can let the collections from solution 2 share the same layout if you want that.

---

#### 1. Using pages

Create a directory structure with index.md pages and loop over the Jekyll veriable called 'site.pages' to create the menu.

```
index.md
topic-a/index.md
  content-1/index.md
  content-2/index.md
  content-3/index.md
topic-b/index.md
  content-1/index.md
  content-2/index.md
  content-3/index.md
```

And loop over all pages like this:

```
<ul>
{% assign sitepages = site.pages | sort: 'order' %}
{% for sitepage in sitepages %}
  <li {% if page.url == sitepage.url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ sitepage.url }}">{{ sitepage.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you want the nested structure, you can do something [like this](https://github.com/jhvanderschee/leec/blob/master/_includes/submenu.html). Or if you want only the results for Topic A, you can do this:

```
<ul>
{% assign sitepages = site.pages | sort: 'order' %}
{% for sitepage in sitepages %}
{% if sitepage.url contains 'topic-a' %}
  <li {% if page.url == sitepage.url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ sitepage.url }}">{{ sitepage.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

#### 2. Using collections (simplest solution and quickest build)

Create a collection Topic A and create another collection Topic B. Your config file should look like this:

```
collections:
  topic-a:
    output: true
    permalink: /topic-a/:path/
  topic-b:
    output: true
    permalink: /topic-b/:path/
```

Outputting the items of one topic goes like this:

```
{% assign atopics = site.topic-a | sort: 'order' %}
{% for atopic in atopics %}
  <li {% if page.url == atopic.url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ atopic.url }}">{{ atopic.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You should create a _topic-a and a _topic-b directory with your content-1.md, content-2.md, etc. files.

---

Note that both solutions have YML variables called 'order', to determine the order of appearance of the items/pages. This looks like this:

```
---
title: mytitle
layout: mylayout
order: 50
---
mycontent
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, but it's not quite what I was intending. The examples you give simply list out all the pages on the site--is there a way to parse out only those entries that are contained in the current folder? E.g. items in `topic-a/index.md` would only include content for topic-a. (Nothing from topic-b or the homepage.)

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to list only Topic A, using the pages approach.

Comment: I agree that the solution 2 is the "cleanest" solution, and it could be even more improved by using, a collection of all this articles and type as an attribute of the collection's element..

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose here 2 ways, you can determine the "best" according to your specific needs/situation, and which one sound more adapted to them.

first of all, "posts" and "pages" are basically just collections of md/html files. with some [variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) associated to each one.

to generate files with this structure, you can:

## 1. Using _posts and page.categories

1. put all the sub-files in `_posts` (the `2017-01-01-` is just a place holder)

   ```
   _posts/
      - 2017-01-01-content-a-1.md
      - 2017-01-01-content-a-2.md
      - 2017-01-01-content-a-3.md
      - 2017-01-01-content-b-1.md
      - 2017-01-01-content-b-2.md
      - 2017-01-01-content-b-3.md
   ```
2. add appropriate categories to each file:

   2.1. for posts `caontent-a-*` add category: topic-a (in this order) by adding this line in the [yaml front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) at top of each of them:

   ```
   ---
    layout: page                  # or any appropriate layout 
    category: topic-a
    ---
   ```

   2.2. for posts `caontent-b-*` add category: topic-b
3. set a [premalink](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) to ignore the date, and create the desired structure, by adding the following line to `_config.yml`:

   ```
   defaults:
    -
      scope:
        path: "_posts" # to all the file in posts
      values:
        permalink: /landing/:categories/:title.html # set this as default permalink value
   ```

you still can specify a permalinks per post in its front matter, or just add the permalink line to each md folder front matter.

the above will generate the desired structure.

4. loop through all the

   ```
   {% for entry in site.posts %}
      {% if entry.category == type-a %}
         <!-- do A stuff -->
      {% elsif entry.category == type-b %}
         <!-- do B stuff -->
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

## 2. Using collections:

it's similar to the above, but instead of using the already existent `_posts`collection you'll start by [creating a new collection](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) (one advantage is that you'll not need to add a `date` )

any of the approaches above will generate this structure inside `_site`

```
landing/
  type-a/
    content-a-1/
      index.html
    content-a-2/
      index.html
    ...
  type-b/
    ...
```